# How to detect cause of segmentation fault if size of file is unknown?

Tags: c, cs50

Basically I am trying to read from a file, where contents are stored in blocks of 512 bytes.
I know why segmentation faults occur but since I dont know the sizes of the JPEG files, I don't know where I am running into the problem.
The debugger does stop after  calling fread although I have no idea why it does that.

When running the debugger, the loops runs for maybe 40+ times and then it crashes due to segmentation error.

This is the code I am working with so far:
THe buffer has been malloc'ed the size of 512

```
int counter = 0;
char *fileName = (char *) malloc(sizeof(int));
//sprintf(fileName, "%03i.jpg", counter);

FILE *img = NULL;

while(feof(p) == 0)
{
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 512, p);

    if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && ((buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)) //checks if the first four bytes match
    {
        if(img == NULL)
        {
            sprintf(fileName, "%03i.jpg", counter);
            img = fopen(fileName, "w");
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), 512, img);
        }
        else
        {
            counter++;
            sprintf(fileName, "%03i.jpg", counter);
            img = fopen(fileName, "w");
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), 512, img);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //continue writing to existing file
        if(img == NULL)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), 512, img);
        }
    }

    if(feof(p) > 0)
    {
        fclose(p);
        fclose(img);
        free(fileName);
        free(buffer);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `char *fileName = (char *) malloc(sizeof(int));` How much memory do you think that allocates?

Comment: @kaylum how else do i allocate memory for a file I dont know the size of? even when I multiply it by 512. Also, the filename according to my knowledge just stores literally filename from 000.jpg to 049.jpg. or doesn't it?

Comment: Since you're doing the `cs50` "recover" assignment, there are plenty of answers on SO. Just search on `[cs50] recover jpg` and one of the entries you'll get is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62328469/cs50-pset4-recover-unable-to-recover-001-jpg-and-file-0049-jpg-recovered-does

Comment: @CraigEstey I want to learn by doing this through research and whatever help I can get from people checking my codes reason why I don't want to look at the answers.

Comment: Fair enough. Although, this program is so simple, it's hard to give a hint without giving the whole show away. But, take a look at the _top_ part of my answer [i.e. skip the example code]. Reading [or trying to read] the _entire_ input file (i.e. needing to know the file size at all) is the wrong approach [as mentioned in my answer].

Comment: @CraigEstey that's true though it worked like magic understanding that one part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to read 512 bytes at one time.

And, you loop checking for the delimiters and change the output file when you see one.

Since the delimiters are *aligned* on a 512 byte boundary, you *only* want to read 512 bytes at one time--no more and no less.

As I mentioned in my top comments, there are plenty of answers already. But, I responded on a similar question, and produced the following debugged code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool magictag(uint8_t *);

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage:./recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *memorycard = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (!memorycard) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File cannot be opened\n");
        return 2;
    }

    int file_no = 0;
    int b;
    int code = 0;
    uint8_t buf[1000];

    FILE *jpeg = NULL;

    // While haven't reached EOF
    while (1) {
        b = fread(buf, 512, 1, memorycard);
        if (b == 0)
            break;

        int startflg = magictag(buf);

        if (startflg) {
            if (jpeg != NULL)
                fclose(jpeg);

            char outfile[50];
            sprintf(outfile, "%03i.jpg", file_no);
            ++file_no;

            jpeg = fopen(outfile,"w");
            if (jpeg == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "jpg cannot be created\n");
                code = 3;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (jpeg != NULL)
            fwrite(buf, 512, 1, jpeg);
    }

    if (jpeg != NULL)
        fclose(jpeg);

    fclose(memorycard);

    return code;
}

bool
magictag(uint8_t *c)
{
    bool ret = false;

    do {
        if (c[0] != 0xFF)
            break;
        if (c[1] != 0xD8)
            break;
        if (c[2] != 0xFF)
            break;
        if ((c[3] & 0xF0) != 0xE0)
            break;
        ret = true;
    } while (0);

    return ret;
}
```

Note that the actual question was here: [My recovered images don't match in CS50 PSET4 Recover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63453516/my-recovered-images-dont-match-in-cs50-pset4-recover)

I didn't post the above code because that OP already solved the problem from the comments there.

Comment: Thanks. I did A LOT of research on why I should fread the size of 512 and quantity of 1 versus  fread the size of 1 byte and quantity of 512. 
Thanks, this was the solution and the only problem.

Comment: Good for you! Happy Programming!